# Do structural, historical or philosophical reason(s) explain why native python allow slicing list of lists only with list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Why native python doesn't allow calling a full or a slice of list of lists

```
table=[list(range(10)),list(range(10)),list(range(10))]
#calling the first column
a=table[:][0]
#calling a subset of table
b=table[0:2][1:4]
```

instead of the heavy and overcomplicated list comprehension approach?

```
a = [row[0] for row in table]
b = [row[1:4] for row in table[0:2]]
```

Whereas we can call `c=table[1][0:3]`, why can't python allowed calling for `table[0:2][0:3]` with ease?
**Is there a structural, an historical or a philosophical reason to allow such slicing using only list comprehension?**

Comment: You mean other than the usual "do things one way" maxim? [*"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: sorry, what the point of your comment? You mean that list comprehension would be the usual way?

Comment: That *is* how you do it, yes?

Comment: it is in total contradiction with the zen of python point 1, 2, 3 at least. We do the simple way in numpy and other library so why not in native python is my question. Historically, was using the simple way being rejected for reason(s) (and if so, which are they) or simply not even considered.

Comment: Because `list` objects aren't multidimensional arrays, *they are lists*, heterogenous containers of data. They don't have things like a dimension or a shape. A list of lists is but one of very many use-cases, and not one which the language designers considered requiring a special case for

Comment: Well, I never said it was a good manifesto.  I'm merely pointing out that there is simple precedent if you care to look.

Comment: Anyway, the answer to all such questions is "because that's what the language designers decided to do."  If you want a better answer, you should ask them.

Comment: yes, i'm asking. If you don't know, thank to allow answer to come ;)

Comment: My question is not about opinions, but about facts: structural, philosophical or historical reasons. Kaya3 proposes it would be about a structural reason but I still doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a list comprehension is the straightforward way.

`table[0:2][1:4]` doesn't do what you want because `table[0:2]` is a list of the first two elements of `table`, so `[1:4]` takes a slice of that list which still just contains elements of `table`. Both are slice operations on two-dimensional lists, so there is no semantic reason that one slice should return some unchanged rows while the other slice should return all rows but with only some of the columns.

---

The reason Python does not include such an operation on the built-in list type is probably that the comprehensions are easy enough to write, simple enough to read to understand their meaning, and the need for multi-dimensional slicing of native lists is not that common.

Note also that these are two different kinds of "multi-dimensional slice" - one returns a single column as a one-dimensional list the other returns a new two-dimensional list. Whether you want a sliced column to be one- or two-dimensional will depend on the use-case, and if the built-in `list` class took a stance on which one is "correct" then it could easily lead to problems for some users who expect the other behaviour.

If you need multi-dimensional matrices of elements, the [numpy](https://numpy.org/) package supports a clean syntax for multi-dimensional slicing. You may already be using it for multi-dimensional data anyway, and if you're not then you should consider it.

```py
>>> import numpy
>>> m = numpy.array([list(range(10)), list(range(10)), list(range(10))])
>>> m[:, 0]
array([0, 0, 0])
>>> m[0:2, 1:4]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```